# What's wrong in posting just link answer if it's providing enough information to help the question?

Tags: discussion

What's wrong in posting a link in an answer if it's helping to give information regarding the question?

The person might not have knowledge about that; that's why he's asking the question, right?

Comment: Who told you there's something wrong with posting links in answers?

Comment: @Yannis - OP is asking about link only answers.

Comment: What happens if the linked resource is no longer available? What use is the answer?

Comment: Okay i get it now. Thanks guys

Answer (score 7):

Your link can get invalid. Then the answer which would contain only a link is worthless.

Having some text which at least explains the general concept of something can help even if the link is dead (even just to have some more terms to search for)

Though depending on the topic, if you need to provide a link to a long text as an answer, the question itself may be too broad if you cannot at least explain it in a short way.

I tend to add links as a *"check here to dive into it deeper"* or *"I got this from here"* resource.

Your answer though should not only rely on the content of the link (like I said in case the link gets invalid) .